# How to properly display text with tabs in listbox in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, listbox, matlab-figure

I'm inserting text from a file into my listbox and it ignores the tabs that are between the strings. How can I make it so that it doesn't ignore the tabs and prints it as it is?

My text file:

```
05-WD-3052      19:56:07        03-Apr-2016
06-C-874414     19:57:03        03-Apr-2016
10-G-11         19:58:03        03-Apr-2016
```

What it comes out as in the listbox

[image]

my code:

```
fileID = fopen('Output/LicenseLog.txt','rt');
tScan = textscan(fileID, '%s','Delimiter','');
newScan = tScan{:};
set(handles.listbox1,'String',newScan);
fclose(fileID);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The listbox is respecting the tabs in your input, but you are using a variable-width font so the text isn't lining up like you would expect. You can change the [`FontName`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol-properties.html#property_fontname) property of your listbox to `'FixedWidth'` to use the default fixed-width font or you can set it to any [fixed-width/monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) of your choosing to get the expected result:

```
data = {'05-WD-3052     19:56:07     03-Apr-2016', ...
        '06-C-874414    19:57:03     03-Apr-2016', ...
        '10-G-11        19:58:03     03-Apr-2016'};

u = uicontrol('Style', 'list', ...
              'FontName', 'FixedWidth', ...
              'String', data);
```

[image]

**Update**

After looking at your data a little closer, the issue is that tabs aren't displayed the same way across multiple systems, programs, etc. Some of your rows would actually require *two* tabs to properly align everything when viewing them in your GUI. Because of this, you will probably want to convert your tab-separated lists into lists with explicit spaces using `sprintf`.

```
%// Split the string into groups based on the tabs
pieces = regexp(tScans{1}, '\t+', 'split');
for k = 1:numel(pieces)
    %// Create a 20-character wide padded string for each element
    data{k} = sprintf('%-20s', pieces{k}{:})
end

set(handles.listbox, 'String', data)
```

Or if you want a one-liner:

```
data = cellfun(@(x)sprintf('%-20s', x{:}), regexp(tScan{1}, '\t+', 'split'), 'uni', 0);
set(handles.listbox, 'String', data)
```

When combining this with the fixed-width fonts mentioned above you should get the behavior your want.

[image]

Comment: I put the code into my GUI opening function and what I get is a small box in the bottom left of my GUI. I put up an image of it in the main question.

Comment: Never mind. I fixed it by adding `'Position', [600 124 401 69]`

Comment: For your exact code, rather than creating a *new* listbox I would just do: `set(handles.listbox1, 'FontName', 'FixedWidth')` to change the font of the *existing* listbox

Comment: I just realised that it gives the exact same thing. It still doesn't have the tabs when its reading from the text file.

Comment: @Recap Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: I think it is something to do with the way im reading the data from the text file, because it works fine when i ran the code with the "data" you created.

Comment: Can you post the actual text file? Are you sure that it's tabs/spaces as you think?

Comment: [Text File link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/204rsce1hfatda3/LicenseLog.txt?dl=0) Thats the file in my dropbox. It definitly has tabs because when i print to the file im using `\t`

Comment: That worked perfectly, I wouldnt have been able to come up with that in a million years. Thank you so much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108119/discussion-between-recap-and-suever).